# How do you move to the end of the previous line?

Tags: cursor-motions

Say the cursor is `[]`:

```
A very intelligent turtle
Found programming [U]NIX a hurdle
```

I want to end up here:

```
A very intelligent turtl[e]
Found programming UNIX a hurdle
```

If I were here:

```
A very intelligent turtle
[F]ound programming UNIX a hurdle
```

I could use `ge`.

What I can think of is `kg_` or `k$`. Is there another sequence to consider?

Comment: I like k$, but why do you need to be there? For example, if starting a new line, O. Or if appending, kA is better. Etc.

Comment: It could also be `0<bs>` or `0<left>` depending on `:h 'whichwrap'` setting. But, I'm agree, in most cases one really wants `kA` or `O`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yea it's a good point. I'd have to wait until the next time it comes up. It was likely `kA` or `kS` that I needed.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Ah! I came across it again! It's when I want to do a replace on the last character in the previous line. So I'm looking for something better than `kA<BS>`.

Comment: So, `k$s` or `k$r`?

Comment: Yea, so I guess it's 3 characters either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comments: `k$` is probably the best for Normal mode. Depending on what you want to do, there are other options: `kA`, `kS`, `O`, `k$s`, `k$r`, etc.